# Evaluating variable if statement in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to evaluate a statistics problem via a Monte Carlo method.  In this problem I am generating a random number and comparing it to a fixed probability number stored in a vector array titled `comms_reliability`.  Assuming there is only one variable in the vector array, I am comparing the random number and the probability and tallying the results if the random number is greater than the reliability number.  However, the vector array could also have two values, in which case I am producing two random numbers and comparing them to the two reliability numbers and. If both random numbers are bigger than the reliability numbers, I am tallying the scenarios.  Theoretically this could continue on and on for as many values in the vector array as I want.  However, through a failure of imagination I only know how to code this where the for statement is contained in multiple if statements
 for each possible scenario.  In this implementation I have to copy the same lines of code multiple times, and it also limits the `commms_reliability` array sizes that can be evaluated based on how many times I have copied these lines of code to handle the next array point.  How can I do this where I only need one if statement.  An example of how I have it coded currently is shown below.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int   sample_size       = 1000000;
    std::vector<float> comms_reliability = {0.6,0.6};
    float tally = 0.0;

    // rang() =  random number generator
    // if statement for comms_reliability array of size 1
    if (comms_reliability.size() == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++){
            if (rang() > comms_reliability[0]) tally = tally + 1.0;
        }

    }
    // if statement 2 for comms_reliability array of size 2
    if (comms_reliability.size() == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++){
            if (rang() > comms_reliability[0] && rang() > comms_reliability[1]) tally = tally + 1.0;
        }

    }
    // if statement 3 for comms_reliability array of size 3
    if (comms_reliability.size() == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++){
            if (rang() > comms_reliability[0] && rang() > comms_reliability[1] &&
            rang() > comms_reliability[2]) tally = tally + 1.0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to make sure that all elements of `comms_reliability` satisfy some criterion (namely being less than `rang()`) for each sample.

So make a loop over all elements and test each, or just use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
// Lambda function used to test a single comm_reliability
auto is_reliable = [] (float r) { return rang() > r; };
// Iterate over your samples
for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; ++i) {
  // If all elements satisfy your criterion ...
  if (std::all_of(std::begin(comms_reliability),
                  std::end(comms_reliability),
                  is_reliable)) {
    // .. perform your action
    tally += 1.0;
  }
}
```

Instead of the lambda function you could also use a normal function defined somewhere before:

```
bool is_reliable(float r) {
  return rang() > r;
}
```

Note: Try to improve your variable/function naming.

Comment: That will solve the issue, thank you.  Plus I learned a new C++ functionality that I did not know existed before.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :) I added a link to an online documentation where you can find lots of other "goodies" that the C++ standard library provides.

Answer (score 0):

use a flag to keep the value

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int   sample_size       = 1000000;
    std::vector<float> comms_reliability = {0.6,0.6};
    float tally = 0.0;

    // rang() =  random number generator

        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++){
            boolean flag = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < comms_reliability.size(); j++)
            {
                if (rang() <= comms_reliability[j]) 
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            tally = flag ? tally + 1.0 : tally;
        }
```